# Order of item in a row-edit page

Tags: page-layout

When we use the dot-dot-dot … icon to view or edit a row in a list, that item row appears as a data entry form.
It’s a full page devoted to the data in the single, selected row … with text boxes for entering data in each field.

But the order of the items in this form does not match what the user sees in the usual spreadsheet-like view.
I can control the column order in a view, but I cannot seem to control the order of items in the entry form.

Is there a way to control that?

Answer (score 0):

Open your site with [sharepoint designer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491), navigate to lists and libraries (left navigation pane) and click on your list. Then it should bring up all the properties of the list. There is then a forms section and the editForm.aspx will be the one you're looking at when you select the item.[image]
It'll then bring up the page code, if you're not very experienced open it in safe mode by click on the EditForm.aspx link (it'll stop you messing with links to the master page etc.) and everything that you are then left with that you can change is what makes up your form, so just change the order here.

Answer (score 0):

There is an out-of-the-box setting for this. Perform following steps to do it.

1. Go to `List Settings`
2. Check if `Content Types` is visible after `General Settings` Section. If not then click on `Advanced Settings` in General Settings --> Set `Yes` in `Allow Management of Content Types?` --> `OK`. Now you should be able to see Content Types Options after General Settings in List Settings.
3. Click on `Item` Content Type in List Settings.
4. Click on `Column Order`. Set the column order as per your requirement. and Click `OK`.

Now go back to All Items View of the List. Edit any item and you will be able to see the columns in desired order in the Forms.